# NSDate gave the wrong answer （Objective-C）

Tags: ios, objective-c, nsdate

I want transfer second to Hour and minute , and I don't care the Date. but the codes below gave me a wrong result. I passed "7879"second and it should be converse to '02:11:19' , But it returns 10:11:20 . I don't know Where goes wrong.

[image]
p.s. I noticed that the d-value is 8hours so I think it's about the timeZone.. but as I add the code `formatter.timeZone = [NSTimeZone timeZoneWithName:@"Asia/Shanghai"];` it returned me the same result.

Comment: Try with `NSDate *date = [NSDate date];` and check if still get wrong result ?

Comment: add code also so we can track issue .

Comment: What is timestamp actually? It is seconds from which date/hour?

Comment: You need work in GMT. Instead of this: formatter.timeZone = [NSTimeZone timeZoneWithName:@"Asia/Shanghai"];    Use this:  formatter.timeZone = [NSTimeZone timeZoneForSecondsFromGMT:0];

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Use NSDateComponentsFormatter.

```
NSDateComponentsFormatter *dateComponentsFormatter = [[NSDateComponentsFormatter alloc] init];
dateComponentsFormatter.zeroFormattingBehavior = NSDateComponentsFormatterZeroFormattingBehaviorPad;
dateComponentsFormatter.allowedUnits = (NSCalendarUnitHour | NSCalendarUnitMinute | NSCalendarUnitSecond);
NSLog(@"%@", [dateComponentsFormatter stringFromTimeInterval:7879]);
```

output:

```
2:11:19
```

**Swift 3 version**

```
let dateComponentsFormatter = DateComponentsFormatter()
dateComponentsFormatter.zeroFormattingBehavior = .pad
dateComponentsFormatter.allowedUnits = ([.hour, .minute, .second])
print("\(String(describing: dateComponentsFormatter.string(from: 7879)))")
```